# How to intercept key events while menu is displayed

Tags: android, menu, keyevent, onkeypress, onkeydown

I have already overriden the onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) method of my Activity in oder to log user key presses. I have further extended all Views I use in the layout and overriden the onKeyDown method there as well. That way I can log hardkey presses throughout most of my application. Only if an option menu or context menu is open, i cannot intercept any hard key presses to write them to the logfile. Does anybody know how/whether this can be done? Is it possible to attach an OnKeyListener or OnKeyDownListener to a menu?. Thanks in advance for your help and efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. You can just log the fact that the particular menu item has been choosen.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir for your comment. However, in my case, i am particularly interested in the hard key presses, even the "wrong" ones, e.g. such keys that do not make sense to interface navigation at this point. For example, when the user presses the "down key" instead of "right key" i would like to log this too...